# SharePoint 2016 development environment setup

Tags: sharepoint-server, development-enviroment

## Problem

I am trying to create sharepoint 2016 solution with Visual Studio 2015 but there is no template for Sharepoint 2016. I download update 2 tool for office. but not seeing the template. What I am missing to do this.

### Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683). These tools will provide the 2016 templates.